# Amazon maps fragment replacement

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I've run into an issue while I've been trying to use the [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment)) method to replace a fragment to log onto a server with another map fragment, but this is what occurs: The new fragment (should be an Amazon map fragment) [only takes half of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzWzs.png). It should change to be the new fragment once the user hits the sign in button (and I've tried changing the fragment there as well but I haven't been able to get that to work either).

Currently, I'm calling the new fragment from an Async task's onPostExecute method that checks if the login worked properly. Here's where I call the transaction:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result) {      //If true, the server tasks were successful
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_login_view, createFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Here's the XML file for the second fragment that I'm calling:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              map:amzn_mapType="amzn_normal"
              tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
              class="com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried a number of things with changing this XML file, such as everything listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419695/android-google-maps-xml-layout-errors#comment27059774_18419789), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896093/cant-use-google-map-xml-attributes), along with probably nearly everything listed in the documentation given by Amazon, and various tutorials online.

I also looked at [a question for replacing fragments in an Async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828794/call-a-fragment-in-asyncktask-onpostexecute-method) but to no avail. I know that the replace is somewhat working, as can be seen from the picture I posted up above, but it never seems to take up the entire screen.

My onCreate and onCreateView for the map fragment class are as followed:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isAmazonMapsAvailable()){   //this has always been true
       Log.i(TAG, "Amazon maps is available!"); 
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

I've spent several hours messing around with this code and haven't been able to get the map fragment to fill up the whole screen -- while still displaying a map. I think it must have something to do with my XML file, as I've been able to get it parts of the fragment to display, just not all of the pieces are correct there. I think that I'm doing the replace correctly, and since my Async task is nested, the replace is able to work there just fine.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

**EDIT**

Here's the login_fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_login_view"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userNameHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serverHostHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/server_host"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/serverPortHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/server_port"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameEntry"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingBottom="22dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEntry"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingTop="22dp"
            android:paddingBottom="22dp"
            android:allowUndo="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serverHostEntry"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingTop="22dp"
            android:paddingBottom="22dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/serverPortEntry"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingTop="22dp"
            android:paddingBottom="22dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does the XML where `R.id.fragment_login_view` is look like?
Also in your XML for the `Map Fragment` the `RelativeLayout` is most probably redundant and could be removed.

Comment: @Darwind I've added in the XML file for the login fragment. You're right about the RelativeLayout though. I'm not sure why I had that in there. I removed it from my code and reran it, but I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this! What I did was put both my login fragment AND the map fragment inside FrameLayouts. Only after I did both of that was I able to get my map fragment able to fill the entire screen instead of just a portion. I'm not exactly sure how this was possible -- but here's the new map fragment XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             map:amzn_mapType="amzn_satellite">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              class="com.amazon.geo.mapsv2.MapFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The entire login fragment that's up above I just encapsulated inside of a Frame Layout, with the width and height being "match_parent" and it seemed to work just great!

I have no idea why this works. I just know it does, and if anyone who knows why this is the case, I would greatly appreciate some enlightenment on the topic! Thanks so much!